# Efficient Java List Merging Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, list, arraylist

I have two Java Lists (as in the actual class), each of which has the elements of a numbered list and levels, expressed as String objects. Each line below is a separate string in the List. For example, the first list could be:

```
==level 1==
1.1 2


==level 2==
1.R4 0
2.0 2


==level 3==
3.R3 1
4.R5 1
```

and the second could be:

```
==level 3==
1.null
2.null
```

The lists can each be of any length and the values after the numbers don't matter here. The goal is to merge the lists of the levels that match. For example, a merge of the two lists above would be:

```
==level 1==
1.1 2


==level 2==
1.R4 0
2.0 2


==level 3==
1.null
2.null
3.R3 1
4.R5 1
```

The numbers in the matching levels of the two lists will never be the same, so that does not need to checked for. I also believe that the numbers will always be consecutive. This is what I have so far, but it does not cover all cases, specifically when the merge takes place only at the beginning of a level, or only at the end. It is also quite unpleasant to look at. tempLines and lines are the two lists.

```
for(int x=0; x < lines.size();x++){
            for(int y=0; y < tempLines.size();y++){
                if(tempLines.get(y).equals(lines.get(x)) && !(tempLines.get(y).equals("\n"))&& !(lines.get(x).equals("\n"))){
                    int a=y+1;
                    int b=x+1;
                    while(!(tempLines.get(a).equals("\n"))){
                        while(!(lines.get(b).equals("\n"))){
                            if(Integer.valueOf(tempLines.get(a).charAt(0))==(Integer.valueOf(tempLines.get(a).charAt(0))-1))
                                lines.add(b,tempLines.get(a));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: Are the both input lists always sorted ascending in terms of levels *and* numbers?

Comment: Yes, that is the case.

Comment: I am curious about why this data is being processed as String data, rather than being converted to Java objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that both of your input lists are being sorted ascending you can use the standard approach of merging two sorted lists/arrays. Main point is that you do not need to have nested loops in your algorithm but walk through both lists alternately always appending the lower element to your result and advancing in that list. Here's a sketch respecting the differentiation between numbers and levels.

```
int ix_a = 0;
int ix_b = 0;
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
while (ix_a < A.size() || ix_b < B.size()) {

    // No more elements in A => append everything from B to result
    if (ix_a == A.size()) {
        result.add(B.get(ix_b));
        ix_b++;
        continue;
    }

    // No more elements in B => append everything from A to result
    if (ix_b == B.size()) {
        result.add(A.get(ix_a));
        ix_a++;
        continue;
    } 

    // Always append the lower element and advance in that list. 
    // If both lists contain the same element, append this once and advance in both lists
    // Distinguish between levels and numbers here, levels take higher precedence.
    String a = A.get(ix_a);
    String b = B.get(ix_b);
    if (isLevel(a) && isLevel(b)) {
        if (isLowerLevel(a, b)) {
            result.add(a);
            ix_a++;
        } else if (isLowerLevel(b, a)) {
            result.add(b);
            ix_b++;
        } else {
            result.add(a);
            ix_a++;
            ix_b++;
        }
    } else if (isLevel(a)) {
        result.add(b);
        ix_b++;
    } else if (isLevel(b)) {
        result.add(a);
        ix_a++;
    } else {
        if (isLowerNumber(a, b)) {
            result.add(a);
            ix_a++;
        } else if (isLowerNumber(b, a)) {
            result.add(b);
            ix_b++;
        } else {
            result.add(a);
            ix_a++;
            ix_b++;
        }
    }
}
```

This can be further optimized by leaving out unnecessarily duplicated checks like `isLevel(...)` etc. Also the handling of empty lines has to be added.

Answer (score 1):

I usually work around that problems by processing with `Map`. It is possible to use another collections, such as lists, but I've found that the code using maps is easier to read (and probably not a performance issue, unless your list has million of elements).

In this case, I would have a `Map<Integer,String>` for keeping the entries in the correct order. Such maps will be stored as value in another map, where the key is the level number. I would use `TreeMap` as the implementation class, because it sorts the entries according to their key.

```
Map<Integer,Map<Integer,String>> map = new TreeMap<>();
int level=0; //current level
for (String line:templines) {
 if (line.startsWith("==level ")) { 
   level=Integer.valueOf(line.substring(7).replace("==","").trim());
   if (map.get(level)==null) map.put(level,new TreeMap<>());
 } else if (line.length>0) {
   int pos = line.indexOf('.');
   if (pos>0) {
    int n = Integer.valueOf(line.substring(0,pos));
    line=line.substring(pos+1);
    map.get(level).put(n,line); 
   }
 }
}
```

Once I have the map, I would iterate it and save the values in another list.

```
List<String> merged = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer,Map<Integer,String>> entry:map.entrySet()) {
  list.add("==level "+entry.getKey()+"==");
  for (String line:entry.getValue().values()) {
   list.add(line);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you'll have to use a Map where you put each level as key and a list of lines as a value. after finishing processing the lists to merge, get the key set and sort it descending so you have the level sorted. Then you can start iterating over the map values using the sorted keys/levels. add the level the the dest list, sort the list for the actual level and add all its element to the dest too.

Here is what i came up with:

```
public class MergeLists {

    private final static String[] list1 = {
        "==level 1==\r\n", 
        "1.1 2\r\n", 
        "\r\n", 
        "\r\n", 
        "==level 2==\r\n", 
        "1.R4 0\r\n", 
        "2.0 2\r\n", 
        "\r\n", 
        "\r\n", 
        "==level 3==\r\n", 
        "3.R3 1\r\n", 
        "4.R5 1"
    };

    private final static String[] list2 = {
        "==level 3==\r\n", 
        "1.null\r\n", 
        "2.null"
    };

    @Test
    public void mergLists() {
        List<List<String>> listList = new ArrayList<>();
        listList.add(Arrays.asList(list1));
        listList.add(Arrays.asList(list2));
        List<String> mergedList = mergLists(listList);
        for(String s : mergedList) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public List<String> mergLists(List<List<String>> listList) {
        List<String> mergedList = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, List<String>> levelMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        for(int j = 0; j < listList.size(); j++) {
            List<String> list = listList.get(j);
            String actLevel = null;
            for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                String line = list.get(i).trim();
                if(isLevel(line)) {
                    actLevel = line;
                } else {
                    if(actLevel != null) {
                        List<String> levelList = levelMap.get(actLevel);
                        if(levelList == null) {
                            levelList = new ArrayList<>();
                            levelMap.put(actLevel, levelList);
                        }
                        levelList.add(line);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("line " + (i+1) + " in list " + (j+1) + " does not belong to a level.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        List<String> sortedLevelList = new ArrayList<>(levelMap.keySet());
        Collections.sort(sortedLevelList, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return (extractNumberFromLevel(o1) - extractNumberFromLevel(o2));
            }

            private int extractNumberFromLevel(String level) {
                // check that this meets the format of your level entry (assuming "==level n==")
                int r = 0;
                int i = level.indexOf("level");
                if(i != -1) {
                    int j = level.lastIndexOf("==");
                    if(j != -1) {
                        String n = level.substring(i + "level".length(), j).trim();
                        try {
                            r = Integer.parseInt(n);
                        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                            // ignore and return 0
                        } 
                    }
                }
                return r;
            }
        });

        for(String level : sortedLevelList) {
            List<String> lineList = levelMap.get(level);
            Collections.sort(lineList, new Comparator<String>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                    return o1.trim().length() == 0 ? 1 /* this puts the empty string at the end of the list */ 
                            : (extractNumberFromLine(o1) - extractNumberFromLine(o2));
                }

                private int extractNumberFromLine(String o) {
                    // check that this meets the format of your line entry (assuming "n.1 2")
                    int r = 0;
                    int i = o.indexOf('.');
                    if(i != -1) {
                        String n = o.substring(0, i).trim();
                        try {
                            r = Integer.parseInt(n);
                        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
                            // ignore and return 0
                        }
                    }
                    return r;
                }
            });

            mergedList.add(level);
            mergedList.addAll(lineList);
        }

        return mergedList;
    }

    private boolean isLevel(String line) {
        // check that this meets the format of your level entry (assuming "==level n==")
        return line.contains("level");
    }
}
```

Output

```
==level 1==
1.1 2


==level 2==
1.R4 0
2.0 2


==level 3==
1.null
2.null
3.R3 1
4.R5 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the collection per level and use Apache Commons Collections.

```
Collection a = createCollection();
Collection b = createCollection();

Collection c = CollectionUtils.union(a,b);
```